# Positive self dual Fourier eigenfuctions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Some of the "basic" Fourier eigenfuctions encountered in real and complex analysis are

$$ e^{-\pi x^2}, \quad \frac{1}{\cosh{\pi x}} $$

**What are some other (smooth) functions fixed under the Fourier transform which have different decay rates than the above two functions? (1)**

For $f\in{\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})}$, define

$$\widehat{f}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) e^{-2 \pi i x \xi} dx $$

*Some background:* It is possible to generate additional Fourier eigenfuctions by means of various iterative processes. A classical example are the *Hermite functions*, which may be given by

$$h_k(x) = (-1)^k e^{x^2/2} \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \left( e^{-x^2} \right) $$

$h_0(\sqrt{2 \pi} x) = e^{-\pi x^2}$ and it turns out that $H_k(x) = h_k(\sqrt{2 \pi} x) $ are Fourier eigenfuctions with eigenvalue $(-i)^k$. So, if $\widehat{f} = f$, then it is possible to write

$$ f \sim \sum_m a_{4m}H_{4m} $$

It appears difficult to find the/any correct combination of Hermite functions which create a +1 function satisfying (1).

Alternatively, if we set $ \gamma(x) $ equal to $e^{-\pi x^2} $ or $ \mathrm{sech}\pi x$ from above, then for $a > 1$, the functions $\gamma(x)$, $a\gamma(ax) + \gamma(x/a) $, and $a\gamma(ax) + \gamma(x/a) - (1+a)\gamma(x) $ are +1 eigenfunctions due directly to the dilation property $ f(\delta x) \longrightarrow 1/ \delta \widehat{f}(\xi / \delta) $. The following plot shows these three functions with $ \gamma(x) = \mathrm{sech} \pi x $ and $a=1.5$.

[image: fourier plots]

Although $a \gamma(ax) + \gamma(x/a)$ is another eigenfunction, it's not fundamentally different from $\gamma(x)$. One "problem" (at least in my case) with $ a\gamma(ax) + \gamma(x/a) - (1+a)\gamma(x)$ (in green) is that it oscillates. The higher order Hermite functions also oscillate before decaying rapidly. $\mathrm{sech} \pi x$ decays like $e^{-|x|}$ while the Hermite functions, which take the form $e^{-x^2/2} P(x)$ (P a ploynomial) decay like $e^{-|x|^2}$. I'm wondering **if there are other +1 (self-dual) functions which decay at different rates**. In a sense, I'm trying to reverse an iteration or generating relation, and one possible avenue may be to consider functions of the form

$$ \int_1^\infty (a\gamma(ax) + \gamma(x/a) - (1+a)\gamma(x)) d \sigma (a) $$
where $\sigma$ is a (positive?) measure on $(1,\infty)$. However, it appears that pinning down any particular such measures which make the integral converge is difficult.

Comment: While considering $e^{-\pi x^2}$, rather than $e^{-(1/2)x^2}$, as a function equal to its Fourier transform is telling us how you are defining the Fourier transform implicitly, I think it would be better for the question if you started by giving an explicit definition of $\widehat{f}(x)$.

Comment: Please indicate what you mean by a function not being a "transformation" of $e^{-\pi x^2}$. For instance, do you consider the Hermite functions to be "transformations" of $e^{-\pi x^2}$?

Comment: Transformation in the sense of a stretch or shrink of the function by replacing $x \mapsto \alpha x$. Will edit, thank you.

Comment: I guess what I'm after is a +1 function with a different decay rate than 1 (hyp. secant) or 2 (Gaussian). Not sure how best to ask that...

Comment: With that meaning for transformation (not involving growth estimates), you have already given many answers yourself: $H_{4k}(x)$ and their (possibly infinite) linear combinations are self-dual and not "transformations" of $e^{-\pi x^2}$ or $1/\cosh(\pi x)$. (Note the standard term for a function equal to its Fourier transform is *self-dual* function. Nobody says "+1 function".)

Comment: You don't indicate what function space on the real line you want to be in: $L^1$, $L^2$, something else.  If you can take the Fourier transform twice then for even $f$ the sum $f + \widehat{f}$ is self-dual for "arbitrary" even $f$, so there are many examples that way.

Comment: For my purposes we can restrict to the Schwartz space on the real line. Will edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111678/discussion-between-dan-l-and-kcd).